# Security Group works in Site Collection but not Subsite with Broken Inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a Site Collection with a Security Group called Managers that has read access at the site collection.
I have Subsite A that I subsequently broker inheritance.  Since I still needed to have the security group Managers with read access on subsite A I did not remove this group once I broke inheritance.  However, individuals in this security group are getting denied access messages.

In Subsite B security inherits from the parent and the security group Managers is fine with all users having access to subsite B.

Why do they (individuals in security group Managers) not have access to subsite A ?  Did I need to remove security group Managers and re-add it back to subsite A when I broke inheritance ?

Note this is not a Publishing site and I use SP Enterprise.

Comment: Is the Managers group an AD group or a SharePoint group?

Comment: SharePoint Group

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  I spent hours on this but figured it out !  I went ahead and took off unique permissions for Site A.  People could still not get in and in fact I was getting Access requests from them that indicated they did not have access to the Site Collection ?  How was that possible I thought as all the users could get into the Site Collection link.

Here was the problem.  I made a template of Site B and created Site A using the template for B.  This must somehow hose the permissions because once I went to the Site Collection Site Settings Master Page and I checked all boxes for all categories to Reset all subsites to inherit from site master page for themes, css, etc.

Bingo, then everyone got into Subsite A...

My first ever answer for Stack..give me some props guys :)